# Task Scheduler returns error in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

I'd build an application in VB.net which contains some background procedures to be done every day. The exe was scheduled in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm getting the following error from the system. Whereas when the same scheduler is run manually it runs successfully. There are no multiple processes running during the scheduler process. Can you suggest why it happens?

Error:

> Connection Timeout Expired.
>   The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.
>   The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.
>   The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - 
>   [Pre-Login] initialization=2; handshake=5; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=14001;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something to do with login/credentials access.

Comment: The exe build is run with administrative privileges in task schedular in the server. The problem is some times it runs and some times it doesn't. The schedular log gives no error.